# Where can I change/add the colors available for Calendar Overlay?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, calendar

Where can I change/add the colors available for Calendar Overlay in SharePoint 2010?  We have a branded site (using our own Site Theme).  I only have 2 choices for colors when I create calendar overlays: Dark Red, #5a041c listed 7 times and Gray-50%, #7f7f7 listed 2 times.
On our OOB Test Site I have 9 different color choices.  Where do I add more colors to our branded site?

Comment: The colors should be there automatically, I've never seen colors not appear before. Possibly a glitch. There is no SP provided method of changing or managing these colors.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this yet? I am having the same issue.